# Elliptic R-matrix and Yang Baxter solution for XYZ model

Tags: integrable-systems, spin-chains

in the framework of QISM, How can i derive the R-matrix for XYZ Heisenberg model?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronym QISM.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question of yours: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/397890